# eval javascript, check for syntax error

Tags: javascript, eval

I wanted to know if it is possible to find through javascript if a call to eval() has a syntax error or undefined variable, etc... so lets say I use eval for some arbitrary javascript is there a way to capture the error output of that eval?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can test to see if an error is indeed a SyntaxError.

```
try {
    eval(code); 
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

When using try-catch for catching a particular type of error one should ensure that other types of exceptions are not suppressed. Otherwise if the evaluated code throws a different kind of exception it could disappear and cause unexpected behaviour of the code.

I would suggest writing code like this:

```
try {
    eval(code); 
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        alert(e.message);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Please note the "else" section.

Comment: throw is not a function

Comment: What are you running your code on if throw is not a function? :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Mozilla documentation for `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> eval returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

So I think you may be out of luck. This same document also recommends against using `eval`:

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.

So regardless, please be aware of the risks before using this function.

Comment: About eval being evil, golden rule: Don't eval user input, only eval strings that you defined yourself, for example: from a server. Yes, MiTM attack, but if you can't trust your server, then you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which contains a javascript parser written in javascript. It will give you lots of information about your code, it can be configured to be more relaxed or not, etc...

Answer (score 1):

To continue using the code after validation, I use the following example:

```
var validCode = 1;
try {
  eval( jsCode );        /* Code test */
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
    validCode = 0;
    console.warn(e.message);
  }
} finally {
  if(validCode){
    "do some magic"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Below code posted by  go-oleg thanks to him

This code validate the correct syntax otherwise return error

Note:code is not vaildate run time error because it uses ast parser to analyze the correct syntax.

To Install

```
npm install esprima --save
```

code:

```
var esprima = require('esprima');
var userStringToTest = 'var a = 50;';

var isValid = isValidJs(userStringToTest);

if(isValid) {
  alert('its validated!');
}
else {
  console.log('its NOT valid syntax!');
}

function isValidJs(testString) {
  var isValid = true;
  try {
    esprima.parse(testString);
  }
  catch(e) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> put your desired value for b

```
    //b="4+6";
    try { eval(b); } 
    catch (err) {
       if (err instanceof SyntaxError)
          document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = "<i>Syntax Error</i>";

        /*In html make a div and put id "screen" in it for this to work
        you can also replace this line with document.write or alert as per your wish*/
    }
    finally {
         document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = eval(b); //outputs answer
    }
```