# Test if well formed javascript expression before executing

Tags: javascript, validation, syntax

I have a script which takes user input, performs some operations on that input and then executes the modified input.

**Example:**

User enters 'vbscipt or javascript'

My script converts it to:

```
var searchtest = "mystring.search('vbscript')>=0 || mystring.search('javascript')>=0";
```

And executes it using eval(searchtest);

However if the user enters 'vbscript javascript'

My script converts it to

```
var searchtest = "mystring.search('vbscript')>=0 mystring.search('javascript')>=0";
```

(Note lack of ||) Which will cause an error when I call eval(searchtest);

Is there a way to test the searchtest string to determine if it is a valid javascript expression before executing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923316/eval-javascript-check-for-syntax-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript eval is evil !!

Instead of transforming user input as you are doing why not something like the following :

```
// list of values considered valid
myString = ['javascript', 'vbscript', 'perl', 'python'];

function search (x) {
  // Returns true if x is a value an array (passed as `this`)
  return this.indexOf (x) >= 0;
}

function searchTest (userInput, myString, search) { 'use strict';

  function orClause (clause) {
    // caluse is a series of values separated by `or`, return true
    // if any search returns true for any of the values.
    clause = clause.split (/\s+or\s+/i); // split on 'or'
    while (clause.length) { // for each value
      if (search.apply (myString, [clause.shift ()])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false; // no matches....
  }        

  userInput = userInput.split (/\s+and\s+/i); // split on 'and'

  // userInput is now an array of clauses each is either a value or 
  // a series of values separated by `or`. We pass each clause to
  // the orCaluse function and return true only if ALL returns are true. 
  while (userInput.length) { 
    if (!orClause (userInput.shift ())) { 
       return false; // and fails
    }
  }

  return true;  // All true so return true.
}

searchTest ('fred or javascript and python', myString, search),
```

I am assuming your expresson can be a sequence of `and`s and `or`s with `and`s taking precedence

Comment: Blimey it's gong to take a while to get my head round that. Looks good though. Is this something you've used before?  You assume correctly. The approach I came up with allows complex search strings (a and b) or (c and d) by taking advantage of javascripts inbuilt logic processing. I guess your way does too (but safer)

Comment: I have used this kind of thing many times before. Its called a parser, a simplified version of what compilers use. The idea of creating a language which your users can use is often referred to as a Domain Specific Language. Use the Google to learn more.

Comment: I've commented the code to try and explain its function, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `eval` itself and catch syntax error exceptions. But don't do it! Blindly transforming user input and validating ready to execute code with eval is an open gate for many XSS attacks. Instead of validating transformed string, you should strictly validate user input instead to make absolutely sure that transformation will result in correct code limited only to exact operations you wish to allow.

Comment: I thought you might say that! This isn't for a public site, there are only 4 users and none of them are coders so I'm prepared to take the risk. Thanks though!