# json_encode and javascript constants

Tags: javascript, constants, json

I have come codes like this:

```
<script>
CONT_TEXT = 'Some Text'

var jsobj = <?php json_encode(array(
   'prop1' => 'something',
   'prop2' => 'CONT_TEXT',
   'prop3' => 'location.host',
)) ; ?>;


alert(jsobj.prop2);
alert(jsobj.prop3);
</script>
```

output is:

```
<script>
CONT_TEXT = 'Some Text'

var jsobj = {"prop1":"something","prop2":"CONT_TEXT","prop3":"location.host"};


alert(jsobj.prop2);
alert(jsobj.prop3);
</script>
```

I wanna first alert show: `Some Text` and second show website host property. that means this:

```
<script>
CONT_TEXT = 'Some Text'

var jsobj = {"prop1":"something","prop2":CONT_TEXT,"prop3":location.host};


alert(jsobj.prop2);
alert(jsobj.prop3);
</script>
```

`"` is my problem!

how can I pass javascript constrants via json_encode in PHP?

whats your idea?

Comment: Did you try to display prop3 only?

Comment: JSON can only contain data. You cannot have references to external variables in JSON encoded data. You could encode that information (i.e. a reference to a variable) as (e.g.) string and then decode it on the client side. But you'd have to create your own logic for that. How you encode the information is up to you, there is no best practice for that.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around in the PHP flags for json_encode but could't find anything that would help. So why don't you try to use the javascript `eval()` metode.

like this:

```
alert(eval(jsobj.prop2));
alert(eval(jsobj.prop3));
```

View these docs: [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

I don't know if this is the best way, but i got inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923316/eval-javascript-check-for-syntax-error). Try to use this function instead of eval:

```
function safe_eval(prop)
{
    try {
       return eval(prop);
    } catch (e) {
        return prop;
    }
}
```

It will either return the `eval()`-ed variable value or only the string in case `eval()` fails.

Comment: prop are so much and i dont know which must through eval functions. but +1 for that it is a solution.

Comment: I c. maybe adding meta_data like svidgen or segment your php array in 2 like this: `$prop_array = array("js_variables" => array(...), "plain_text" => array(...))` and then process the values separatly in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "natural" solution. But, nothing prevents you from creating a "protocol" of sorts. You could use an inner object with a particular key to replace with the constant values as-needed.

```
{"a":"text", "b":{"_ref":"CONST"}}
```

Or give each object a type:

```
{
  "__type": "SomeClass",
  "propertyA": "valueA",
  "propertyB": {
    "__type": "Reference",
    "value": "CONST"
   }
}
```

And instantiate them accordingly. Something *like* this [completely untested code]:

```
function instantiate(o, classRepository) {
  var rv;
  var classes = classRepository || window;

  if (o.__type && classes[o.__type] && typeof(classes[o.__type]) == 'function') {
    rv = new classes[o.__type]();
  } else {
    rv = {};
  }

  // instantiate all potentially instantiable child objects
  for (var i in o) {
    if (typeof(o[i]) == 'object') {
      rv[i] = instantiate(o[i]);
    } else {
      rv[i] = o[i];
    }
  }

  return rv;
}

var typedObject = instantiate(untypedObject);
```

An alternative to copying properties over after object construction might be to set a pattern wherein all constructors accept an object from which to consume only the relevant properties.

Comment: if give me a fiddle or complete functions to do this, I click this answer as `accepted answer`.

Comment: @EmRa228: Don't you understand the answer or what's your problem? We help you to find a solution, but we don't code *everything* for you. You have to do a little on your own. Or pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: @FelixKling I didnt understood that answer and with an example maybe I found it!

Comment: @EmRa228 I'll pass on the fiddle. I've added some untested sample code to hopefully set you in ***a*** right direction though ...

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking of another way. I don't think it's a very "clean" way but since you are echo-ing a string in php, you could also process this string and simply remove the quotes, e.g. with some regex [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$json_string = json_encode(array(
     'prop1' => 'something',
     'prop2' => 'CONT_TEXT',
     'prop3' => 'location.host',
)) ;

echo preg_replace('/("prop2":|"prop3":)"([a-zA-Z_\.]+)"/', '$1$2', $json_string);
```

Just a thought

Comment: That might work in this case, but not when you really have to parse the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

The javascript constrant is clientsite and php serverside. You may try using an ajax call passing a get parameter with the content of your constrant but that is a bit of a workaround.

Comment: PHP(server side) not need to know values of javascript constrant. just must echo `var jsobj = {"prop1":"something","prop2":CONT_TEXT,"prop3":location.host};`. JS do jobs yourself.