# Testing/validating/evaluating the outcome of every path in a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

*Disclaimer - I've tried finding an answer to this via google/stackoverflow, but I don't know how to define the problem (I don't know the proper term)*

I have many small AI snippets such as what follows. There is an `._ai` snippet (like below) per enemy type, with one function `next()` which is called by the finite state machine in the main game loop (fyi: the `next` function doesn't get called every update iteration, only when the enemy is shifted from the queue).

**The question:** How do I test every case (taking into account some enemy AI snippets might be more complex, having cases that may occur 1 in 1000 turns) and ensure the code is valid?

In the example below, if I added the line `blabla/1` under count++, the error might not crop for a long time, as the Javascript interpreter won't catch the error until it hits that particular path. In compiled languages, adding garbage such as `blabla/1` would be caught at compile time.

```
// AI Snippet
this._ai = (function(commands){
    var count = 0;

    return {
        next: function(onDone, goodies, baddies) {

            // If the internal counter reaches
            // 2, launch a super attack and 
            // reset the count
            if(count >= 2) {
                commands.super(onDone);
                count = 0;
            }
            else {
                // If not performing the super attack
                // there is a 50% chance of calling
                // the `attack` command
                if(chance(50)) {
                    var target = goodies[0];
                    commands.attack(onDone, target);
                } 
                // Or a 50% chance of calling the 
                // `charge` command
                else {
                    commands.charge(onDone);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    };
})(this._commands);
```

I could rig the random generator to return a table of values from `0-n` and run `next` 1000's of times against each number. I just don't feel like that is will concretely tell me every path is error free.

Comment: "ensure the code is valid" -- What defined validitiy ?

Comment: Valid is perhaps the wrong wording, I mean error free. In the sense that all pathes won't throw errors

Comment: you can only test pure functions automatically. since calling your same function twice in a row can return different results, there's no way to test every outcome.

Comment: Surely there are options. Refactoring the code is not out of the question

Comment: This is undecidable problem, I can proove this if you want.

Comment: @mas.morozov Can you define undecidable?

Comment: Is it not possible, with some refactoring, to pull all branches into there own functions (like `function commandCharge() { commands.charge(onDone); count++; }`) then keep a list of functions to loop over an execute each one individually to test if they work without error? Another, broader option, would be to use TypeScript which would error check when it compiles from `ts` to `js`

Comment: I do not need to define it, because undecidability is well known strict mathematical notion - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem

Comment: And why bother about erorrs? You can just catch them, even syntax errors - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923316/eval-javascript-check-for-syntax-error) Infinite looping (inside `next`) will be the real headache! If there was multithreaded environment - it would be best to run such code in separate thread and terminate it after predefined timeout. But most JS implementations does not feature real threading.

Comment: Thats a good point. Do you mean that running it through eval will throw syntax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, unit tests must test every path so you will be sure all works well.

But you should be able to decide which path the method will follow before calling it on your tests, so you're be able to know if the method behaviour is the expected one, and if there is any error.

So, for example, if there is a path that will be followed in only one of every 1000 executions, you shouldn't need to test all 0, 1, 2 ... 999 cases. You only one combination of results that behave distinctly.

For example, in the snippet shown you have these cases:

- the counter has reached 2
- the counter has not reached 2 and chance returns true
- the counter has not reached 2 and chance returns false

One way to archieve this is taking control of the counter and of the chance method by mocking them.

If you want to know what happens when the counter has reached 2 and the next method is called, just pass a counter with 2 and call next. You don't need to reach 2 on the counter by really passing for all the code.

As for the randomizer, you don't need to try until the randomizer returns the value you want to test. Make it a mock and configure it to behave as you need for each case.

I hope this helps.