# Check eval equation

Tags: javascript, eval

Using eval to calculate string. Is there any way to check if the data that passed to EVAL() is valid.

```
var apa = "12/5*9+9.4*2";
alert(eval(apa));
```

If apa = "asaa+3 - 5"; for example, console will say

> Uncaught ReferenceError: asaais not defined at eval

Comment: Define "valid".

Comment: I think you can check if it throws.

Comment: You can parse it.... There is no way to know it is valid before you run it. You can...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval javascript, check for syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923316/eval-javascript-check-for-syntax-error)

Comment: If you're going to check for validity anyway (which means that you'll be using a parser) then there's no reason to use `eval`.

Comment: `asaa` is a valid JS identifier, so that could very well be a valid string. You might get a `ReferenceError` though if it's not defined

Comment: Also make sure that you eval string is safe to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether the result of the evaluation is undefined first. If so, the expression was invalid.

```
var apa = "12/5*9+9.4*2";
var apaResult = eval(apa);
if (apaResult != undefined) {
    alert(apaResult);
} else {
    alert("Could not evaluate expression")
}
```

Comment: But that gives error in console, "ReferenceError: asaa is not defined". Or there is no way to get rid of this?

Comment: You can wrap eval in a try catch block. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z27my96g/)

Comment: try {
    eval(apaResult ); 
}  gives me same error... "ReferenceError: asaa is not defined
    at eval "