# Show "Syntax Error" if eval() can not evaluate a given string

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, eval, calculator

I am building a small project of making a simple Calculator using HTML, CSS & Javascript.
I am using **eval function**. I wanted to have both features of **Math Error** and **Syntax Error** like a real calculator and I have successfully added Math Error feature but I couldn't add the Syntax Error.
So the problem is,
If I do this:

```js
var a = "2+2";
alert(eval(a));
```

It shows the right answer: 4.
But If I do this:

```js
var a = "2++2";
alert(eval(a));
```

Or this:

```
document.write(eval(a));
```

then the eval function is not executed and shows nothing on screen.
It shows this on the console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix
> operation

But I want it to show just a "Syntax Error" on the screen.

Comment: When I run that, I **do** get a *`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eval javascript, check for syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923316/eval-javascript-check-for-syntax-error)

Comment: It works for me (`SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand`)

Comment: @Bergi I need to edit my question.

Comment: Just use `try`/`catch` to handle the error by displaying it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `try/catch` block to catch the exception thrown by `eval`, and use [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/name) on the error object to print only its class name. Which, in this case, is `SyntaxError`.

```js
var a = "2++2";
try {
    alert(eval(a));
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.name);
}
```

You can also do custom handling for different errors (as well as custom error messages) by simply inspecting `e.name` and printing whatever you want.

Note that the `console.error` prints to `stderr`, instead of the usual `stdout` from `console.log`. You can change this if you want.